# Do asserts check database data or submitted form data?

Tags: forms, symfony, null, constraints, field

I have a file input I don't want to be null when I update the form (when I create it, the default value is null, that's why I allow it to be null in DB).

Here is what my entity looks like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
#[Assert\NotNull]
private $idCard;

public function getIdCard(): ?string
{
    return $this->idCard;
}

public function setIdCard(?string $idCard): self
{
    $this->idCard = $idCard;

    return $this;
}
```

And my form type:

```
->add('idCard', FileType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'label'    => 'Choose a file'
        ])
```

In my database, this property is null, because nothing has been uploaded yet. But when I try to upload something, it throws me the error "This value should not be null". I tried the same thing replacing NULL by '' (blank) in database and it worked. It's like the constraints were checking database instead of submitted form data. If it's the case, how can I just check if my field data isn't null (server side) and throw an error if it is ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, which was to set `mapped => true` instead of `mapped => false`, so it can create a link between the entity and the form.